# Elliptic Curves - can point addition never hit the third point?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Can it so happen that "adding" two points of Elliptic Curve (over finite field) never "hits" any third point of that curve? For example `Y^2 = X^3 - 6*X + 7` over `GF19` looks like this, (unless there is mistake):

[image: Elliptic curve example over GF19]

Taking two leftmost points `P = (0, 11)` and `Q = (3, 15)` it seems the tangent gradient is `k = (15 - 11) * inv(3 - 0)` where `inv(3)` seems to be `13`, and thus `k = 4 * 13 = 14`. The "line" between these points is `Y = 14 * X + 11`, right?

Seemingly it never got to any other of the marked points except these two. Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong, or coefficients `A, B, P` should be chosen with some special rule to make points addition "more lucky"?

Comment: By plugging in $y=14x+11$ into $y^2=x^3-6x+7$ you get the cubic equation
$$p(x)=x^3+13x^2+9x\equiv x(x^2-6x+9)=0.$$
Hence the polynomial $p(x)$ factors over $GF(19)$ as
$$p(x)=x(x-3)^2.$$ 
So the third point is $x=3$ as three is a double root. In other words, the line $y=14x+11$ is the tangent of the elliptic curve at $Q$.

Comment: For the purposes of elliptic curve addition this means that $P+Q+Q=0$. In other words $P+Q=-Q=(3,4)$. You might have figured out this right away, if you had applied the point doubling formula to $Q$. You would the similarly calculate that $[2]Q=-P=(0,8)$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure we have covered similar examples on the site earlier. Therefore I'm reluctant to post this as an answer. Anyway, I have upvoted your question, for it has good context, and you explained the situation very well. I (or someone else) will promote the comment to an answer, if we cannot find a good duplicate target.

Comment: For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2932640/11619) we similarly see from prof. Lubin's answer how a double root arises in case of a tangent.

Comment: A similar situation is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2474783/11619). Though there the situation is even more special as the line happens to be horizontal. But for the purposes of elliptic curve arithmetic slope zero is not really a special case.

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042634/11619). None of these questions is similar enough to call this a duplicate, but there are more to be checked out.

Comment: [One more](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/880314/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks a lot for details and examples! not sure if converting these ideas to proper answer will really harm :) I'm sure I googled a bit before asking and there were no close search results (perhaps no close keyword set) so your explanations could be pretty useful for others.

Comment: You can convert them to an answer if you like, since @JyrkiLahtonen hasn't done so and has indicated he's not likely to do so.